# Aggregation date range mystery

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have this kind of mongo

```
$date = (int)(date("YmdHis", strtotime("now -30 days")));
$date2 = (int)(date("YmdHis", strtotime("now")));    

$visits_options2 = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
                'date' => array('$lte'=>$date2, '$gte'=>$date),
                'click'=>1
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                "_id"=>array({LOT OF FIELDS}),
                'cpc' => array('$sum' => '$cpc'),
                'visits' => array('$sum'=>1)
            )
        )
    );
```

The mystery comes when (having data for sure) if I only use `'$gte'` on match it works but if I use both `$gte` and `$lte` it doesn't.

Any clue of whats happening?

**UPDATE**: Ok, so it got weirder. If I use `gte + lte` on console (exact same query) it works. If I use only gte and the "now" Date console says there are no results (works fine) and mongo driver returns results as if i used the "-30 days" date. Looks funny.

**SOLVED**: Just for anyone with the same problem, update mongo driver and everything works fine!

Comment: Have you tried including `ago` in your format e.g. `$date = (int)(date("YmdHis", strtotime("now -30 days ago")));` or since you are using 30 days for a month (which is not good as there are other months with 31 or 28 or 29 days), just use `$date = (int)(date("YmdHis", strtotime("-1 month"));` ?

Comment: Didnt tryed, i was just using a random range that im sure has results. Anyway i just tested it in another server and it works so.. I think all this is comming from a outdated driver.